# CakePHP bypassing validation rules

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I have a `Post` model which has the following validation rules:

```
public $validate = array(
    'title' => array(
        'between' => array(
            'rule' => array('between', 1, 60),
            'message' => 'Between 1 and 60 characters in length'
        ),
        'format' => array(
            'rule' => array('custom', '~[a-zA-Z0-9\s-]~'),
            'message' => 'Alphanumeric characters, spaces and dashes (-) only'
        )
    ),
    'body' => array(
        'between' => array(
            'rule' => array('between', 1, 65535),
            'message' => 'Between 1 and 65535 characters in length'
        )
    ),
    'slug' => array(
        'between' => array(
            'rule' => array('between', 1, 60),
            'message' => 'Between 1 and 60 characters in length'
        ),
        'format' => array(
            'rule' => array('custom', '~[a-zA-Z0-9-]~'),
            'message' => 'Alphanumeric characters and dashes (-) only'
        )
    )
);
```

I also have a view to insert a new post which looks like this:

```
<?php $this->Html->script('add-post', array('inline' => false)); ?>

<h1>Add post</h1>

<?php echo $this->Form->create('Post'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('title'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('body'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('slug'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Publish'); ?>
```

Now, when I submit the form with the title being something like `blog post title £$&£$^£$` it goes through and gets inserted, despite the regex not matching the symbols in that title. This happens on all fields where regex is used to check the format.

However, if I try to submit a post which doesn't pass the `between` rule (like a title over 60 characters) it successfully throws up a validation error.

What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex pattern is only checking that at least one of those characters is found *anywhere* in the string. So if you were to post just `£$&£$^£$` by itself it would fail because the valid characters aren't found anywhere in that string. You should replace the rule with this:

```
~^[a-zA-Z0-9\s-]+$~
```